# Primefaces: setPropertyActionListener. Parameter gets null value

Tags: datagrid, primefaces, parameters, null, actionlistener

I have a dataGrid that iterates a list of object. In each  grid I have a commandButton and a  tag that tries to put the Id of the object selected in the backing bean, but when action is executed, and also in the setter method of the property, the value is null.

Here is my code:

```
<p:dataGrid var="element" value="#{CentroController.profiles}" columns="3"  
 rows="10" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink}  {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" > 
     <p:panel header="#{CentroController.getDescripcionRoot(element)}" style="text-align:center">  
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%">  

         <p:panel>
             <p:commandButton value="Borrar perfil" icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":form:tabView:profileButtonPanel" action="#{CentroController.deletePerfil}"> 
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{element.id}" target="#{CentroController.selectedItemId}" />
             </p:commandButton>
          </p:panel>
      </h:panelGrid>  
     </p:panel> 
</p:dataGrid>
```

In the backing bean:

```
public void deletePerfil()
{
    System.out.println("SELECTED ITEM ID: " + this.selectedItemId);
     // selectedItemID is always null
}
```

When setter is called, the value is also null:

```
public void setSelectedItemId(BigDecimal selectedItemId) {

    System.out.println(selectedItemId); // Value is null
    this.selectedItemId = selectedItemId;
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: the code of the bean (I removed irrelevant methods).

```
/* imports */

@Named("CentroController")
@SessionScoped

public class CentroController implements Serializable{

private @Inject CentrosDAO dao;
private @Inject CentrosCanalesDAO daoServicios;
private @Inject CatalogoCentrosLaboratorioDAO habitualLabDAO;
private @Inject CatalogoCentrosRadiologiaDAO habitualRadDAO;

private List<Centros> centros;  
private Centros selectedCentro;
private List<CentrosCanales> selectedCanales=new ArrayList<CentrosCanales>();

private List<CentrosCanales> listado;  
private CentrosCanales selected;
private CatalogoCentros selectedItem;
private BigDecimal selectedItemId;
private TreeNode root;
private DualListModel<Catalogo> listCatalogo;
private DualListModel <Catalogo> listCatalogoLabHabitual;
private DualListModel <Catalogo> listCatalogoRadHabitual;

private CatalogoCentros perfilNuevo=new CatalogoCentros();
private @Inject CentrosCanalesDAO consulta;
private @Inject CatalogoCentrosDAO consulta1;
private @Inject CatalogoDAO consulta2;

private boolean servicioIsSelected; //, perfilIsSelected, pruebaIsSelected;

private List<CatalogoCentros> profiles;

public CentroController() { 
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.centros=dao.obtenListaCentros();
    servicioIsSelected = false;
    //perfilIsSelected = false;
}

public BigDecimal getSelectedItemId() {
    return selectedItemId;
}

public void setSelectedItemId(BigDecimal selectedItemId) {

    System.out.println(selectedItemId);
    this.selectedItemId = selectedItemId;
}

public void deletePerfil()
{
    System.out.println("SELECTED ITEM ID: " + this.selectedItemId);
}
}
```

**UPDATED**

The dataGrid is inside a rowExpansion tag within a datatable. I realized that if I put the dataGrid outside instead of nested in the datatable, it works. But I want it in the rowExpansion.

It only works If I put the datagrid outside of the tabView in which is included.

Comment: Use a `<h:outputText value="ID: #{element.id}"/>` to check if the value is actually `null`.

Comment: I've already tried that, the value is the expected value. Thanks

Comment: A comment: Bean is SessionScoped.

Comment: Please post the code of the Bean.

Comment: Try the following: change `deletePerfil` to `deletePerfil(CatalogoCentros)` remove the setPropertyActionListener and use `action="#{CentroController.deletePerfil(element)}"` and observe if this gives the wanted results.

Comment: I've already tried that too, and the parameter is null again :S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some questions about CatalogoCentros:

1. Is the *id* field a BigDecimal?
2. Did you override the hashCode and equals?

If "no" to question 2, do something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) ? id.intValue() : 0;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof CatalogoCentros) {
        CatalogoCentros item = (CatalogoCentros) obj;
        return item.getId().equals(getId());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Set a breakpoint in your *equals* method and see if that gets tripped when you select something in the dataGrid.

Comment: Hello. 1. Yes, id is a BigDecimal.  2. No. I overrided them now and the equals method doesn't get tripped when I click on the commandButton (the datagrid is not selectable). I've tried using the id and the whole object as a parameter of the method and it didn't work either. Thanks.